# returning a boolean in one line for a ball that has crashed into another ball

Tags: java, return, boolean, user-defined-functions

I've just started learning java this quarter and on a sample quiz, this is a question. I have no idea where to begin save for the fact that it has to return a `boolean` type.

*Fill in the blank so that this function returns true if the circle at x1, y1, with radius r1, has collided with the circle at x2, y2, with radius r2.*

```
boolean collided(int x1, int y1, int r1, int x2, int y2, int r2) {
    return ___________________________________________________________;
}
```

Appreciate the comments and kind help. Like I said above, if you had read it, **I've just started learning java this quarter and on a sample quiz, this is a question I had no idea where to begin**. If anyone is willing to direct me to another learning resource that is better suited for a complete beginner, that would be great.

Comment: This is more of a [math question](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm).

Comment: ehm ... do you know what "colliding" means? do you know how to check whether a collision occured?

Comment: It's not a java code, you need to leave that site immediately, real java will be: Ball one = new Ball(x,y,z); Ball another = new Ball(x,y,z); one.collided(another); <- returns boolean

Comment: StackOverflow is not a platform where others are going to do your homework.. Please add some informations what you have tried, add some code, etc

Answer (score 1):

Balls are collided when distance between their centers is less than sum of their radiuses.

Distance is `sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)`

`sqrt` is square root, `a^b` is power (`a^2` is `a*a`).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of code this is:

```
boolean collided(int x1, int y1, int r1, int x2, int y2, int r2) {
  return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1)) < r1+r2;
}
```

That statement consists of the calculcation of the distance between the two circles's centers and checking if that distance is less than the sum of the two radiuses. That check returns a boolean value, `true` if the circles "collided"

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean collided(int x1, int y1, int r1, int x2, int y2, int r2) 
{
  return !(Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2))>(r1+r2));
}
```